# Proxy_url for kibana in metricbeat.yml

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, amazon-elasticsearch, metricbeat

My server requires proxy to connect to kibana. How can I specify that in metricbeat.yml file. For output.elasticsearch there is attribute called proxy_url but I cant see for kibana

Answer (score 0):

From metricsbeat you can send beats data elasticsearch as well setup dashboard to kibana.

Do you need proxy for setup dashboard ? If so proxy environment will work for you.

On Linux/Unix simply export proxy variable as below

```
export http_proxy=http://host:port/
export https_proxy=http://host:port/
```

and then run the setup such as below.

```
./metricbeat setup --dashboards
```

For sending only beats data you already have proxy_url under elasticsearch output module